# Shadow catcher plane transparency problem in compositing

Tags: rendering, transparency, compositing-nodes, world, shadowcatcher

[image]I'm new to blender and need some help with compositing. I tracked a video footage to camera solve and placed a 3d car in compositing. Shadow catcher plane showing world background on my footage floor under the car instead of showing shadow on floor. Shadow catcher plane is casting shadows but cropping my footage floor where shadow catcher plane is placed.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow... could you show some screenshots to clarify? What means the shadow catcher plane shows the world background on the footage floor? With footage floor you mean the floor which is seen in the footage? And the shadow catcher plane casts shadows onto what? Just a quick guess from me: in the _Visibility > Mask_ settings of the shadow catcher plane, where _Shadow Catcher_ is enabled, is there also _Holdout_ checked? It sounds a bit like that if I understand it correctly.

Comment: yes you got it right. Footage floor where I am trying to place 3d car is suppose to have shadow under the car, but the shadow catcher plane is showing world HDR through that plane shape also casting shadow on that. and no holdout is unchecked.

Comment: So your scene consists of the car and the shadow catcher plane. And how do you get your footage into the scene?

Comment: by movie clip editor and then camera tracked. I tried so many things but nothing worked.

Comment: No, I mean in the compositing. How do you get your movie clip to be rendered under the car and shadow plane? With an _Image Texture_ node and _Alpha Over_ node, or do you have an object in your scene with the movie clip as texture? Maybe it would be best to upload a file with your setup or at least show screenshots. To upload a file take this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: its a movie clip node to undistortion node and then scale node to 2 alpha over nodes. Don't know much about nodes, still learning. project is uploading.

Comment: With the screenshot it's a lot easier. Do you render your scene with a visible background? Then I might have an answer.

Comment: Please don't delete the images and links on the question, without them the question is not clear. Think that other users that have the same issue can use your question to solve their problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To alpha over your rendered car and shadow above your footage, the background needs to be transparent. Go to *Render Settings* > *Film* > *Transparent* and enable it.

[image]

Comment: By the way, to ensure that the plane catches the complete shadow and it's not cut off somewhere giving a sharp border, I would suggest you make the plane a lot bigger. Since it's invisible it won't make a difference for the result (as long as the shadow is projected onto the floor, not the other car or anything else that's not lying flat under it).

Comment: God bless you..Problem solved. :) Thank you so so much